# Can a Giant Flytrap in Pathfinder engulf a medium creature?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters

For a Giant Flytrap in Pathfinder, the rules text indicates: "If a giant flytrap begins its turn with an *opponent at least two size categories smaller* than itself grappled..., it can close its jaws completely around the foe...". Does that mean it can engulf medium creatures, or it can't?

Note that I read through [this](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2ky3u?Giant-Flytraps) message board post, which indicates it can't. However, I disagree since I interpret "at least two size categories smaller than itself" to be smaller than or equal to medium, as opposed to smaller than medium.

Comment: If a random internet person in a forum thread contradicts your own good sense, don't listen to the random internet person.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [flytrap](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/plants/flytrap-giant) is size Huge, so it can engulf Medium creatures.

A large creature is one size smaller.  A medium creature is two sizes smaller.  Therefore, a medium creature is "at least two sizes smaller".

I don't see anything that even contradicts this in the linked thread, which is mostly about Grab and not Engulf.  If you still have qualms, could you point to the specific post that made you think this?

Comment: The thread [contains a statement](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2ky3u?Giant-Flytraps#2) that it can grab opponents two sizes smaller, instead of the default one size smaller, and then they parenthetically say "(< Medium)". But then later they say "so they can grab medium creatures". They're just writing comparison notation wrong in the thread.

Comment: @starwed: I just wanted to double check that my interpretation was correct.